# Creating md5 checksum while copying file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, performance, file, copy, md5

I want to create a Ruby program that copies files from a SD card to a harddisk as fast as possible, but also creates a md5 checksums of the source AND the destination file to ensure data integrity.

I believe that reading the file in chunks and creating the checksum as i go along will be faster than

- create checksums of source
- copy the file
- create checksum of target

  $md5 = Digest::MD5.file('filename').hexdigest 
  creates the checksum, but i dont know how to make md5 creation and file duplication happen at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate the digest while streaming the file to avoid re-reading the file.

```
def copy_md5(source, target)
  chunk_size=1024
  md5 = Digest::MD5.new
  open(target,'w') do |t|
    open(source) do |s|
      while chunk=s.read(chunk_size)
        md5.update chunk
        t.write chunk
      end
    end
  end
  md5
end
```

Comment: You completely answered the original question i posted. In the meantime i found a different hash function though https://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-xxHash/versions/0.3.0 (ruby-xxHash) which seems to be faster for my (non-cryptopgraphic) checksum needs!